# Should my Json storage handle exceptions?

Tags: c#, json, error-handling

I made a class to conviniently serialize/deserialize data. Now I'm stuck with the following question. Should I handle exceptions (use try-catch) inside `JsonStorage` or inside `ConfigManager` and other classes that might use `JsonStorage` in the future?

```
public class JsonStorage : IDataStorage
{
    private readonly IFileSystem fileSystem;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public JsonStorage(IFileSystem fileSystem, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public T RestoreObject<T>(string path)
    {
        T result = default;

        try
        {
            if (!fileSystem.Path.IsPathFullyQualified(path))
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid path.", nameof(path));

            string json = fileSystem.File.ReadAllText($"{path}.json");
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Log($"Object can't be restored. {ex.Message}");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void StoreObject(object obj, string path)
    {
        string file = $"{path}.json";

        try
        {
            if (!fileSystem.Path.IsPathFullyQualified(path))
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid path.", nameof(path));

            fileSystem.Directory.CreateDirectory(fileSystem.Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
            fileSystem.File.WriteAllText(file, json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Log($"Object can't be stored. {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static class ConfigManager
{
    private static readonly string configPath = @"SomePath\Config";

    public static BotConfig LoadConfig()
    {
        return Unity.Resolve<IDataStorage>().RestoreObject<BotConfig>(configPath);
    }

    public static void SaveConfig(BotConfig config)
    {
        Unity.Resolve<IDataStorage>().StoreObject(config, configPath);
    }
}
```

`ConfigManager` - example class that holds a path to Config.json and loads/saves it (using `JsonStorage` internaly).

For now I'm catching exceptions inside `JsonStorage` and using a logger instance to print exception messages to the console.
I don't know if there's a downside to that. Should `JsonStorage` have its own logger? Should it throw an exception (just like `ReadAllText`/`WriteAllText`) when something goes wrong with path/files?
Or maybe there is a good practice and some better ways to handle exceptions (in my particular case)?

Comment: [***"Hint**: If your title contains a question, it is likely a bad title."*](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions/2438#2438)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I see things...

- Throwing `ArgumentException` insinde a `try/catch` that at the same time *swollows* it is pointless. You use `ArgumentException` to inform the user that he called your API in a wrong way. This is not something one should hangle because he won't see it until he looks at the logs. The app should crash in this case.
- The message of the `ArgumentException` is too generic. When it happens, the user already knows something is wrong. Tell him how to fix that by giving him a hint what the correct path should be and what path he actually used.
- The way you are handling exceptions that might be thrown by the json-serializer is unexpected (non-standard) because the user will wonder why he got a `null` without noticing anything. `public` library APIs should always `throw` unless they are called `TryDoSomething` and `return` a `bool`.
- Yet another flaw of this *pattern* is that it doesn't help anyone to find the source of the exception. You neither add the filename to it nor the object that it tried to de/serialize. This is very important piece of information and should be included.

So, what you can/should do instead is to `throw` a new exception that adds more information about what happened e.g.:

```
public T RestoreObject<T>(string path)
{
    if (!fileSystem.Path.IsPathFullyQualified(path))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid path: '{path}'. It must by fully qualified.", nameof(path));

    try
    {    
        string json = fileSystem.File.ReadAllText($"{path}.json");
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new JsonStorageException($"Could not restore object '{typeof(T).Name}' from '{path}'.", ex);
    }
}
```

You'll be happy to see the type and file name when something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for good tips. But what if `ReadAllText` throws some IO exception? In your code it will be re-thrown as `JsonStorageException` and it also doesn't provide details about what went wrong there...

Comment: @Glitch you pass the original exception as inner-exception. See the last parameter.

Comment: oh, didn't notice that. So you're also saying that I shouldn't have logger instance in my storages, and instead should handle thrown exceptions higher up the stack call?

Comment: @Glitch exactly, otherwise you have to check the result against `null` and break the execution there by doing something else. It's easier to use an exception for this especially that you already have one and it doesn't cost anything.